# SVG clipPath not working in Firefox when defined dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, svg

I have the following code:

```
<div class="blah" style="clip-path: url(#clippath)"></div>
<svg width="0" height="0"><defs><clipPath id="clippath">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100"></rect>
</clipPath></defs></svg>
```

This correctly clips the `blah` div to 100x100 square. However, if I use JavaScript to add the svg to the DOM (rather than it being there from page load), it no longer works. Specifically, I'd like to create a dynamic clip path based on events happening in my app.

What am I doing wrong? This only needs to work in Firefox (which unfortunately doesn't support `clip-path: polygon(...)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are you using the namespace variant of createElement.

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "clipPath");
```

If you are just using `createElement()` then the element will be going into the default namespace (ie HTML) and won't be recognised by the SVG renderer.